# Grails databinding date format

Tags: grails, grails-orm, jodatime, grails-2.0

I have a problem within a grails 2.3 application, when it comes to data binding and correct date formats.

I use a datepicker (jQuery ui) that provides a  `<input type="hidden" />` that holds the selected date in ISO_8601 format. It will post a value like this: `2015-08-14` to the controller. The form itself and the post result is correct.

I use this simplified model:

```
class Thing {

    DateTime lastUpdated

    static constraints = {
        lastUpdated nullable: true
    }
}
```

---

### when I try to create an entity, I will face this error message:

`Invalid format: "2015-08-14" is malformed at "15-08-14"`

---

A first research lead me to this change in the `Config.groovy`:

`jodatime.format.html5 = true`

(Link 3 in the list below)

Appying this leads to change. Now the error message is:

`Invalid format: "2015-08-14" is too short` (*flip table*)

---

Another try was to change the databinding.dateFormats to this (also in the Config.groovy):

`grails.databinding.dateFormats = [ "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S","yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'", "yyyy-MM-dd"]`

Which has no effect what so ever.

---

For my understanding a given date format should automatically be marshaled in a dateTime object. What configuration did I miss?

---

Here are relative question, that sadly did not help me:

- [bind date to command object in Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241914/bind-date-to-command-object-in-grails/17243717#17243717)
- [GORM default Date format when sending date to Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057317/gorm-default-date-format-when-sending-date-to-grails)
- [Grails unable to unmarshall date/time from JSON back into joda DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567078/grails-unable-to-unmarshall-date-time-from-json-back-into-joda-datetime)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180431/how-change-joda-time-default-datetime-format-in-grails

Comment: @Ilya thank you for your reply. I'am quite new to grails and do not fully understand how this can help. Should I put this: `jodatime {  format.org.joda.time.DateTime = "yyyy-MM-dd" }`? - this seems so wrong. Is there a connection between input and display style? **Update:** This do work, but is it a good idea to switch the dateTime format to a date only format?

Comment: @Ilya may you want to post this as an answer? This seems to solve the problem. I still have to understand the impact of this change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add next line in **config.groovy**

```
jodatime { format.org.joda.time.DateTime = "yyyy-MM-dd" }
```

But if you don't need time in this field, it's better to use `LocalDate` instead of `DateTime` here.

```
class Thing {  
   LocalDate lastUpdated;
```

...

```
jodatime {   
   format.org.joda.time.DateTime = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" 
   format.org.joda.time.LocalDate = "yyyy-MM-dd" 
}
```

So you will use `DateTime` where you need date with time and `LocalDate` where date is enough

Comment: Thank you for your time. This was driving me insane ;) Now everything seems to work like expected.